# Multiple vue.js containers in kubernetes and terraform setup returns 404 or 502

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

I have an Ingress / Terraform / NGINX / Kubernetes setup that has issues with properly redirecting, it's currently serving a vue.js frontend and a .NET Core backend, both of these work online. However, when adding another Vue.JS instance it doesn't seem to properly redirect to said URL.

My terraform setup

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
    metadata {
     name      = "ingress"
     namespace = var.namespace_name
     annotations = {
       "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect" = true
       "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect" = true
       "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": true
       "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"
     }
    }

spec {
 tls {
  hosts = [var.domain_name, "*.${var.domain_name}"]
  secret_name = "tls-secret"
 }
rule {
  host = var.domain_name
  http {
    path {
      path = "/"
      backend {
        service_name = "frontend"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/api"
      backend {
        service_name = "api"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/backend/*"
      backend {
        service_name = "backend"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

    path {
      path = "/payment/*"
      backend {
        service_name = "payment"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }

  }
}
}

wait_for_load_balancer = true
}
```

When running `kubectl describe` the following is returned

```
Name:             ingress
Namespace:        [redacted]
Address:          [ip-address]
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
 tls-secret terminates [url-name],*.[url-name]
Rules:
  Host            Path  Backends
  ----            ----  --------
  [url-name]
              /           frontend:80 (10.244.0.97:80)
              /api        api:80 (10.244.0.121:80)
              /backend/   backend:80 (10.244.0.96:80)
              /payment/   payment:80 (10.244.0.32:80)
  Annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect:    true
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect:  true
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:          true
```

I was thinking I might be missing proxy settings but I have no idea how to redirect that. Furthermore, this entire solution is deployed with CI and to digital ocean. I've tried various other configurations such as removing the asterix in the paths `/backend/` but this didn't change anything.

In annotations adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` only broke the `/api` URL and didn't fix the others.

EDIT* adding `"kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"` like @Vitalii mentioned unfortunately did not fix the issue. Question has been updated for completeness sake

Comment: I dont see annotation, that explicitly sais you are using Nginx ingress controller, not oob one. First of all add ` kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

Comment: An Ingress Resource object is a collection of L7 rules for routing inbound traffic to Kubernetes Services. Multiple rules can be defined in one Ingress Resource or they can be split up into multiple Ingress Resource manifests. The Ingress Resource also determines which controller to utilize to serve traffic. This can be set with an annotation, kubernetes.io/ingress.class, in the metadata section of the Ingress Resource. For the NGINX controller, use the value nginx as shown below:

Comment: annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

Comment: I've added said annotation, unfortunately, nothing really changed, I do thank you for the additional explanation, that clears up quite a bit. I've also added said annotation to the question for completeness' sake.

Comment: It seems that when adding the rewrite rule again and changing the paths to `/frontend(.*)` the vue containers started working. My API is not functioning because of this though so I've added a separate question for that specific case.

Comment: I see you resolved issue with regex in separate thread. Plz post here also answer for consistency and future searches

Comment: I'll add my answer indeed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` was actually part of the solution, it did break the .NET C# API which made me ask a separate question that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597967/nginx-ingress-rewrite-target-breaks-link-to-net-core-api) for consistency & future searches sake the solution I've used was as follows. apart from adding the rewrite target line in my `annotations` changing the API path from

```
 path {
  path = "/api(.*)"
  backend {
    service_name = "api"
    service_port = 80
  }
}
```

Into

```
     path {
      path = "/(api.*)"
      backend {
        service_name = "olc-api"
        service_port = 80
      }
    }
```

With this it matches the /api to my .NET core app, instead of it trying to find a URL within the vue.js container(s)